# vue-router Failed to resolve async component default: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors~demo failed

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I wrote my program with `Laravel` and `Vuejs` and it works fine on the `localhost`, but it gets an error on the `host`.

**Problem:**

The program runs well on local host, but when I put it on the host, the following error is appears:

> [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default:
> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors~demo failed

```
ChunkLoadError: "Loading chunk vendors~demo failed.
(missing: http://example.com/vendors~demo.js)"
    requireEnsure http://example.com/js/manifest.js:127
    component webpack-internal:///./resources/js/router.js:56
    resolveAsyncComponents webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1904
    flatMapComponents webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1931
    flatMapComponents webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1931
    flatMapComponents webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1930
    resolveAsyncComponents webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1866
    iterator webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2121
    step webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1847
    step webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1851
    step webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1851
    step webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1848
    iterator webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2140
    _callee$ webpack-internal:///./resources/js/permission.js:109
```

**What I did:**

- I assumed that the files might not be properly located on the host, but that was not the problem.
- The next possibility was to update `Webpack`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After several attempts, I used the following command to get the compiled `js` files, which was a mistake. **These are good for development purposes**.

```
npm run watch # npm run development -- --watch
```

or

```
yarn watch
```

*Use the following command to get the output:*

```
npm run prod
```

---

### Script in package.json

```js
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
...
```

Comment: Running `yarn watch` triggers a defined command in your package.json scripts which you didn't mention. I don't think this is a feasible solution